# Read text file from specific position and store in two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, file, text

I have text file which contains line like  this:

```
@relation SMILEfeatures
@attribute pcm_LOGenergy_sma_range numeric
@attribute pcm_LOGenergy_sma_maxPos numeric
@attribute pcm_LOGenergy_sma_minPos numeric...
```

Where are about 6000 lines of these attributes, after attributes where are lines like this:

```
@data
1.283827e+01,3.800000e+01,2.000000e+00,5.331364e+00
1.850000e+02,4.054457e+01,4.500000e+01,3.200000e+01...
```

I need to seperate these strings in two different arrays. So far I only managed to store everything in one array.

Here is my code for storing in array:

```
 using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    String line;

                   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                            sb.AppendLine(line);
                    }
                 }
               string allines = sb.ToString();
               Console.WriteLine(sb);
                 }
```

Comment: what is the question? and which strings should be in the second array?

Comment: All strings which starts with `@relation SMILEfeatures` and contains @attribute should be stored in first array. Numbers which starts with `@data` should be stored in second array.

Comment: means one string = one line? or is the @data only before every paragraph?

Comment: I mean lines. There is one big paragraph with attributes after that another paragraph with numbers.

Comment: At the moment you are reading all of the text that is in the file, aren't you ? A simpler way to achieve this would be: string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath); For getting specified party of the text I would recommend using the String.Split() method if you have delimited parts or String.Substring() method if you have a fixed scheme in your text. The System.String class has lots of methods to work with, checkout the MSDN to find a fitting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All strings after @relation SMILEfeatures and contains @attribute are stored in first array. All the strings after @data should are stored in the second array. Hope this is what you wanted.

```
        var relationLineNumbers = new List<int>();
        var dataLineNumbers = new List<int>();
        var relation = new StringBuilder();
        var data = new List<string>();

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line;
                bool isRelation = false;
                bool isData = false;

                int lineNumber = 0;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lineNumber++;

                    if (line.StartsWith("@relation SMILEfeatures"))
                    {
                        isRelation = true;
                        isData = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (line.StartsWith("@data"))
                    {
                        isData = true;
                        isRelation = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (isRelation)
                    {
                        if (line.StartsWith("@attribute"))
                        {
                            relation.Append(line);
                            relationLineNumbers.Add(lineNumber);
                        }
                    }

                    if (isData)
                    {
                        data.AddRange(line.Split(','));
                        dataLineNumbers.Add(lineNumber);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Relation");
            Console.WriteLine(relation.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Data");
            data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: How i can split string? I  wrote `sbData.append(line.split(','))` but it's not working. I missing something or did it wrong?

Comment: I have edited the code snippet. Since you wanted to split the data, I have used a list instead of string builder.

Comment: One more question. I need to know in which line specific attributes are and store line numbers in array. How to do that?  For example I need to know in which lines this attribute is and store lines numbers in array: `@attribute pcm_LOGenergy_sma`_range

Comment: you need to use a integer to store the line count and increment the line count in the while loop. Create two arrays for line numbers and add the line numbers when you append to stringbuilder/list

Answer (score 0):

> All strings which starts with @relation SMILEfeatures and contains @attribute should be stored in first array. Numbers which starts with @data should be stored in second array.

Use `string.Contains()` and `string.StatsWith()` for checking.

Read every line and decide in wich array / list you want to put this line

```
void ReadAndSortInArrays(string fileLocation)
{
    List<string> noData = new List<string>();
    List<string> Data = new List<string>();

    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation))
    {
        string line;

        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            if(line.StartsWith("@relation") && line.Contains("@attribute"))
            {
                noData.Add(line);
            }
            else if(line.StartsWith("@data")
            {
                Data.Add(line);
            }
            else
            {
                // This is stange
            }
        }
    }

    var noDataArray = noData.ToArray();
    var DataArray = Data.ToArray();
}
```

---

But i think that not every line is beginning with "@data"

So you may want to Read all lines and do somethink like this:

```
string allLines;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(yourfile))
{
    allLines = = sr.ReadToEnd();
}


var arrays = allLines.Split("@data");

// arrays[0] is the part before @data
// arrays[1] is the part after @data (the numbers)
// But array[1] does not contain @data
```

Comment: You could also use `File.ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really very clear. But my take is, collect all lines that start with @relation or @attribute in one bucket, then collect all number lines in another bucket. I have chosen to ignore the @data lines, as they do not seem to contain any extra information.

Error checking may be performed by making sure that the data lines (i.e. number lines) contain comma separated lists of parsable numerical values.

```
var dataLines = new List<string>();
var relAttLines = new List<string>();

foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines())
{
    if (line.StartsWith("@relation") || line.StartsWith("@attribute"))
        relAttLines.Add(line);
    else if (line.StartsWith("@data"))
        //ignore these
        continue;
    else
        dataLines.Add(line);
}
```